# Displaying two decimals without it conflicting with methods

Tags: ruby, methods

I am trying to convert a numeric output given by the user so that it always shows 2 decimals. I know that '%.2f' %  exists, but it always displays this error "string can't be coerced into fixnum" (I think it conflicts with the methods)

Here's my code:

```
hash = {}
entry = " "

 while entry != "q"
  print "Enter your item: "
  item = gets.chomp

  print "Enter the associated cost: "
  cost = gets.chomp.to_f.round(2)

  print "Press any key to continue or 'q' to quit: "
  entry = gets.chomp


hash[item] = cost

end

puts "Receipt: "
puts "----------"

hash.each do |k,v|
puts "#{k} => $#{v}"

end

puts "----------"

print "subtotal: "

subtotal = hash.values.inject(0, :+)


print "$"
puts  '%.2f' % subtotal.round(2)

print "tax: $"
tax = subtotal * 0.06 
puts '%.2f' % tax.round(2)

print "total: $"
total = subtotal + tax
puts  '%.2f' % total.round(2)
```

So basically this step:

```
hash.each do |k,v|
puts "#{k} => $#{v}"
```

For instance, when I input a cost of 1 in a step before it will show it as

$1.0 and not $1.00

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
hash.each do |k,v|
  puts "#{k} => $#{'%.2f' % v}"
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly!

Comment: @Vroryn great, best of luck with your coding.